# Facebook friends list api for swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-friends

I have tried to get the facebook friends list for an IOS app, but receiving empty response from facebook.

How to get face book friends list in swift?

Comment: Please show some related code.

Comment: Here your app statue is in Live and  submit your app for review with required permissions.  See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u/54782732#54782732

Answer (score 14):

In Graph API v2.0 or above, calling /me/friends returns the person's friends who installed the same apps. Additionally, you must request the user_friends permission from each user. user_friends is no longer included by default in every login. Each user must grant the user_friends permission in order to appear in the response to /me/friends.

To get the list of friends who are using your app use following code:

```
    let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, name, email, picture"]
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: params)
    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            let errorMessage = error.localizedDescription 
            /* Handle error */
        }
        else if result.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary){
            /*  handle response */
        }
    }
```

If you want to access a list of non-app-using friends, then use following code:

```
    let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, name, email, picture"]
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends", parameters: params)
    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            let errorMessage = error.localizedDescription 
        }
        else if result.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary){    
            /* Handle response */
        }
    }
```

Comment: **graphPath: "me/friends** fetching only count of friends

Comment: @Himanshu Mahajan, I tried your two codes but I'm not getting friends list. This is my response is :  success(response: FacebookCore.GraphResponse(rawResponse: Optional({
    data =     (
    );
}))) . When i use  "me/friends" I'm getting only count.

Comment: @Himanshu Mahajan Ae you got the list?, if yes. Please help me... Thank you.

Comment: Does this GraphAPI return the email id of friends?

Answer (score 10):

For fetching the friend list must allow user permission **user_friends** at the time of login.
For **swift 3.0** add below code for fetching friend list:

```
let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, name, email, picture"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends", parameters: params).start { (connection, result , error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
        else {
            print(result!)
            //Do further work with response
        }
    }
```

I hope it works!

Comment: This edge was deprecated on April 4th, 2018 and now returns an empty data set.

Comment: @ Alex Shvets, Here your app statue is in Live and  submit your app for review with required permissions.  See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u/54782732#54782732

Answer (score 8):

Remember only those friends are fetched who are using your app and u should have taken users read permission for **user_friends** while logging.

```
var fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/friends", parameters: nil);
            fbRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    println("Friends are : \(result)")

                } else {

                    println("Error Getting Friends \(error)");

                }
            }
```

Refer to : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends#read

Comment: Is there a way to see "all friends" including those who have not installed the same app?

Comment: @VanDuTran i don't think so that u would be able to get all the friends. From new SDK u are able to get only those friends who have installed the app.

Answer (score 7):

Just making an union here that solved my problems:

From Dheeraj Singh, to **get friends using your app**:

```c
var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/friends", parameters: nil);

request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        println("Friends are : \(result)")
    } else {
        println("Error Getting Friends \(error)");
    }
}
```

And to **get all facebook friends**, from Meghs Dhameliya, ported to swift:

```c
var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/taggable_friends", parameters: nil);

request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        println("Friends are : \(result)")
    } else {
        println("Error Getting Friends \(error)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I need all friends but `taggable_friends` return a extrange id different to facebookId

Answer (score 3):

you can get friend list using taggable_friends
[Graph API Reference for User Taggable Friend](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/)

```
  /* make the API call */
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/taggable_friends"
                          completionHandler:^(
                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                              id result,
                              NSError *error
                          ) {
                              /* handle the result */
                          }];
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift - 4
This will only return your facebook friends using the same app.

```
// First you have to check that `user_friends` has associated with your `Access Token`, If you are getting false, please allow allow this field while you login through facebook.
if FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("user_friends") {

        // Prepare your request
        let request = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: params, httpMethod: "GET")

        // Make a call using request
        let _ = request?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
              print("Friends Result: \(String(describing: result))")
        })
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error : Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKAccessToken', Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKGraphRequest' . I imported import FacebookLogin
import FacebookCore

Answer (score 1):

With **user_friends** permission you can have access  to the list of your friends *that also* use your app, so if your app is not used by any of your friend, the list will be empty. See [user_friends permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_friends) reference